# Как сделать RecyclerView с навигацией в глубину?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Вот пример из приложения McDonalds, где в фрагменте "Меню" есть RecyclerView, при нажатии на любой элемент которого появляется точно такой же RecyclerView (только с измененным наполнением, которое зависит от выбранного элемента),и при следующем нажатии это снова повторяется. Как можно реализовать точно такую же навигацию? (и как передавать данные о выбранной кнопке в такой сложной структуре) Кто уже сталкивался с этим?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: адаптер 1го рециклера => (инфо через интерфейс) => активити => обновить адаптер 2го рециклера (передать новый список)

Comment: Можно один ресайклер и менять адаптеры

Comment: @Valgaal, а как адаптеры менять?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать с помощью стека и адаптеров, если у вас адаптеры с разными моделями данных.
Например, у меня будет экран с глубиной три. Первый уровень - это FirstAdapter с моделью FoodListModel. Второй уровень -  это SecondAdapter с моделью FoodTypeModel. Третий уровень - это ThirdAdapter с моделью FoodModel.

Делаем интерфейс-коллбэк, который может принимать любой объект.

```
public interface OnItemClickListener<T> {
    void onClick(T t);
}
```

Потом в нашей активити в коллбэке мы проверяем объект на тип и в зависимости от этого создаем адаптер, который нужен.

Стек тут используется, чтобы поддержать обратную навигацию через кнопку назад.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

    private RecyclerView rv;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter myAdapter;
    private Stack<RecyclerView.Adapter> adapterStack = new Stack<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        myAdapter = new FirstAdapter(this);
        rv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(Object o) {
        adapterStack.push(myAdapter);
        if(o instanceof FoodListModel) {
           //тут можно подгрузить данные и положить в адаптер
           myAdapter = new SecondAdapter(this);
        }
        if(o instanceof FoodTypeModel) {
           //тут можно подгрузить данные и положить в адаптер
           myAdapter = new ThirdAdapter(this)
        };
        if(o instanceof FoodModel) {
           //можно стартануть активити с покупкой
        };
        rv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(!adapterStack.isEmpty()) {
            myAdapter = adapterStack.pop();
            rv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        }else{ //если пустой стек значит мы на первом списке и можно выйти с экрана
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Если модели данных одинаковые можно использовать один адаптер и экзмепляры адаптеров складывать в стек без проверки, но тогда нужно будет решить проблему того, как понять, что мы достигли конца и открыть конечный экран. В самом примере из мака последний экран отличается, поэтому адаптер там другой.

Comment: а если RecyclerView находится в фрагменте, то мы все равно это пишем в главном активити?

Comment: пишите, где угодно, я пример показал. если у вас фрагмент делаете тоже самое только с фрагментом

Comment: А что в интерфейсt за T и (T t)? Там же вроде указываем int position

Comment: Он нужен , чтобы передать объект в активити. В адаптере должно быть что-то типа mCallback.onClick(mList.get(i)); Вместо позиции передаёте объект

Comment: также не распознает super.onBackPressed()

Comment: а если адаптер не изменяется, а просто нужно обновлять данные в зависимости от выбранных элементов?